# Função Linq não retorna Lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Olá, tenho uma aplicação e ela não retorna uma lista que faço SELECT via Linq-to-Sql

O erro pode está no SELECT que o linq-to-sql está fazendo.

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Codigo] AS [Codigo], 
[Extent1].[NomeFantasia] AS [NomeFantasia], 
[Extent1].[RazaoSocial] AS [RazaoSocial], 
[Extent1].[IE] AS [IE], 
[Extent1].[CNPJ] AS [CNPJ], 
[Extent1].[Ativo] AS [Ativo], 
[Extent1].[Fornecedor_Codigo] AS [Fornecedor_Codigo] 
FROM [dbo].[Fornecedors] AS [Extent1]
```

Repare na minha última linha de código minha table chama `Fornecedor` e não `Fornecedors`. Ele deve estar fazendo a pluralização via Entity Framework.

Model:

```
public partial class Fornecedor
{

    public Fornecedor()
    {
        this.Entrada = new HashSet<Entrada>();
        this.Produto = new HashSet<Produto>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Nome fantasia é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Razão Social é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inscrição Estadual é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string IE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CNPJ é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> Ativo { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Entrada> Entrada { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produto { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fornecedor> CollectionFornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

Meu Context:

```
public class SistemaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

Meu Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View(db.Fornecedores.Where(s => s.Ativo == true).ToList());
 }
```

Já tentei colocar um `[Table("Fornecedor")]`, mas aparece esse erro:
The model backing the 'SistemaContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

De princípio não estava usando o *Code First*, mas acredito que por usar alguns *DataAnnotations* ele interpreta que quero usar o *Code First*.

Answer (score 1):

Está quase tudo certo. Alguns ajustes são necessários.

Retire isto:

```
public Fornecedor()
{
    this.Entrada = new HashSet<Entrada>();
    this.Produto = new HashSet<Produto>();
}
```

Propriedades de navegação devem ser inicializadas pelo Entity Framework. Não por você.

Ficaria assim:

```
[Table("Fornecedor")]
public partial class Fornecedor
{    
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Nome fantasia é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Razão Social é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Inscrição Estadual é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string IE { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CNPJ é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> Ativo { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Entrada> Entrada { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produto { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Fornecedor> CollectionFornecedores { get; set; }
}
```

---

Sobre isto:

> The model backing the 'SistemaContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

No Package Manager Console (View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console), digite:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

Aguarde o Visual Studio configurar seu projeto, depois repita os passos para gerar sua *Migration* novamente:

```
PM> Add-Migration Inicial
PM> Update-Database
```

Comment: Só pra constar, faltou retirar o código do construtor no exemplo de baixo

Comment: É mesmo. Obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado a vocês.

Me respondam uma pergunta, qual é a vantagem de usar Code First?

Comment: Várias, eu diria. Controle incremental do banco. Não usar SQL pra nada. Montar o banco através do código da aplicação. Só vejo vantagens.

Comment: Obrigado.
Ele continua não fazendo a seleção, porém não aparece mais o Fornecedors.

Para me certificar que o problema estava no código:
`public ActionResult Index()
        {     
              return View(db.Fornecedores.Where(s => s.Ativo == false).ToList());
        }`

Instanciei um objeto Fornecedor e Criei uma Lista com 3 fornecedores, agora aparece esse 3 fornecedores.

Então meu problema está no `db.Fornecedores.Where(s => s.Ativo == false).ToList()`

Comment: Isto é meio prolixo: `db.Fornecedores.Where(s => s.Ativo == false).ToList()`. Use `db.Fornecedores.Where(s => !s.Ativo).ToList()`. Verifique também como estão as colunas no banco. Parece ser algo simples.

Comment: Continua errado.
Será que meu problema está no context?

`public DbSet<Fornecedor> Fornecedores { get; set; }`

Comment: Não sei. Eu conferiria a base.